# What are the various fictional metals in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: comics, marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I think the question is self explanatory.

**In the Marvel Universe what are the various fictional materials(metals or otherwise)?**

The only ones which I have encountered are:

- Adamantium,
- Vibranium and
- uru.

Are there any besides these?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Marvel's canon Earth-616 is rife with imaginary metals and metallic alloys. The short list includes:**

- **Primary Adamantium:** most indestructible material/metal in the Marvel Universe, found uniquely within [Captain America's shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%27s_shield) *(now with added Uru!).*
- **Adamantium:** incredibly hard to come by, can be used to coat normal metals to enhance their durability as well. Almost impossible to make on Earth-616, process is limited to a select few corporations. Most notably found in [Ultron's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultron) nigh-indestructible carapace.
- **[Secondary Adamantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium#Secondary_adamantium):** When you can't afford real adamantium, you make, buy or steal this. Nearly as good, far more durable than normal metallic alloys, very, very expensive.
- **[Adamantium Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium#Adamantium_beta):** Wolverine's Skeleton and claws are made from this. Unique to Wolverine.
- **[Vibranium A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Wakandan_variety):** A metallic substance which absorbs vibrational energy, once found exclusively in the African kingdom of Wakanda. It was of extraterrestrial origins. The Wakandan stockpile was destroyed.
- **[Vibranium B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Antarctic_variety):** Also known as anti-metal, which destroys metallic bonds even in adamantium. Black Panther used to have claws made from it. This material was found exclusively in the Savage Land.
- **[Carbonadium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Carbonadium):** Carbonadium is a resilient, unstable metal that is vastly stronger than steel, but more malleable and cheaper than adamantium, a synthetic and poor man's adamantium, very durable but also very toxic as well. Most commonly associated with Omega Red.
- **Adamantine:** Greek god's version of Adamantium, durable, tough, golden-colored, very rare. Most notable object: [Hercules' Golden Mace](http://www.comicvine.com/golden-mace/4055-44829/)
- **Uru:** Norse super-metal, [Mjolnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uru_%28comics%29#Background) is made of from it; tough, strong, holds enchantments well, hard to come by, even in Asgard, dwarves horde it.
- **Cosmically-enhanced metals:** including the armor of the [Celestials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_%28comics%29), [Galactus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus) and the material the [Silver Surfer's board](http://marvel.wikia.com/Silver_Surfer%27s_Surfboard) are made of super-strong, nearly indestructible materials, unable to be affected by most normal forces on Earth. This may also include unique weapons of the local god-like beings associated with Earth, such as [Odin's spear, Gungnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_%28comics%29).
- **Iron Man's Armor:** - composed of metallic and ceramically enhanced alloys allowing for durability, strength and can be further enhanced by charging it with electrical energies.
- **Osmium:** A real metal, it makes this list because [Colossus, the Living Juggernaut's](http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_%28Piotr_Rasputin%29) mutant power is to transform into a being composed of this dense and resilient metal.

Comment: Osmium, heaviest on earth.

Comment: Perhaps a special note for Cap's shield (I know it's an alloy but it is unique as well)

Comment: I said uniquely...

Comment: @Thaddeus apologies, I must have skimmed right over that the first time!

Comment: No worries, mate. You are working all over the place so I can understand if you skim entries...

Comment: Osmium is *brittle*, not resilient.

Comment: Gravitonium, from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. Atomic number 123, mass 308 (according to a slide presentation in "The Asset" (Episode 3), so it is unbitrium. Therefore arguably not fictional. But since no one has ever made any beyond Z = 118, I think it qualifies.

Answer (score 5):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_elements,_materials,_isotopes_and_atomic_particles :

- Adamantium (with varying versions, e.g. Beta, Carbonadium etc...)
- Omnium steel
- Shazamium (may be nonmetal)
- Promethium
- Sivanium
- Vibranium
- Uru

Comment: I'm omitting all the non-fictional ones (Promethium, Osmium, steel, whatever alloy Iron Man uses) as well as metal-like stuff that's not named (Silver Surfer's skin)

Comment: ...Shazamium?!?

Comment: Sivanium and Shazamium (and a third metal, Marvelium) were from a Golden-Age Captain Marvel (the Fawcett hero, the SHAZAM! guy) story, reprinted a few times by DC Comics. So, not from Marvel Comics, but nonetheless examples of fictional metals.